# How to catch the app_home_open event from Slack in a BotFramework bot

Tags: c#, botframework, slack

Slack recently added a "Welcome message" requirement for published bots. The bot needs to listen to the [app_home_opened](https://api.slack.com/events/app_home_opened) event sent by the Slack API.
[image: screenshot of the welcome message requirement]

But BotFramework bots don't connect to the Slack API directly.

Is there a way to catch that event through the BotFramework? Similar to the ConversationUpdate/ContactRelationUpdate activity types sent for Teams and Skype?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) it seams that botframework only support a list of specific Slack events, but not this one. So I would suggest to open a feature request issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues

Comment: Can you post where Slack mentions a "Welcome message" requirement? I'm not finding it in their docs.

Comment: I can't find it as a requirement in their documentation either, but it shows up in the check list when you want to submit the app. I've added a screenshot in the original post.

Comment: Performed some additional testing to see if that scope might be captured by the "OnUnrecognizedActivityTypeAsync" function, however I was unsuccessful. I noticed some other scopes that *should* be recognized are also not being picked up. I believe Slack has made a few changes that need to be updated in BotFramework. The submitted [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5486) is helpful.